# If else statment and switch statement about condition of element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm doing a if else and switch statement's comparison using javascript and jquery library. It is about classification of body mass index and each classification output different suggest diet. Both statements can't run and I can't catch the problem.

This is classification of body mass index:

```
const underweight = "underweight"
const healthy = "healthy"
const overweight = "overweight"
const obese = "obesity"
const obeseI = "obese Grade I"
const obeseII = "obese Grade II"
const obeseIII = "obese Grade III"

$(".underweight").hide();
$(".normalweight").hide();
$(".overweight").hide();
```

This is an if else statement:

```
if ( $(".Classification").val() == underweight ){
    $(".underweight").show()

}else if ( $(".Classification").val() == healthy ) {
    $(".healthy").show()

}else if ( $(".Classification").val() == obese 
        || $(".Classification").val() == obeseI 
        || $(".Classification").val() == obeseII 
        || $(".Classification").val() == obeseIII){
    $(".overweight").show()
}
```

This is switch statements:

```
switch ($(".Classification").val()){
case underweight:
    $(".underweight").show();
    break;

case healthy:
    $(".normalweight").show();
    break;

case overweight:
case obese:
case obeseI:
case obeseII:
case obeseIII:
    $(".overweight").show();
    break;

default:
    $("ul").hide()
```

}

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] - I am sure we can cut this script down to much less lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use an object
2. use the index of the keys of the object

```js
const texts = {
  "underweight": "underweight",
  "healthy": "healthy",
  "overweight": "overweight",
  "obese": "obesity",
  "obeseI": "obese Grade I",
  "obeseII": "obese Grade II",
  "obeseIII": "obese Grade III"
};
const arr = Object.keys(texts);
$(function() { // on page load
  $(".Classification").on("change", function() {
    let value = this.value;
    let index = arr.indexOf(value);
    console.log(texts[value]);
    $(".underweight").toggle(index === 0);
    $(".healthy").toggle(index === 1);
    $(".overweight").toggle(index >= 2);
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="Classification">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="underweight">Underweight</option>
  <option value="healthy">Healthy</option>
  <option value="overweight">Overweight</option>
  <option value="obese">Obese</option>
  <option value="obeseI">Obese I</option>
  <option value="obeseII">Obese II</option>
  <option value="obeseIII">Obese III</option>
</select>
<div class="text underweight">Underweight</div>
<div class="text healthy">Healthy</div>
<div class="text overweight">Overweight</div>
```

If you gave numerical values in the select, you could save `arr.indexOf(value);`